# how to return mp3 file in django view

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm creating audio upload/download app with django and
I want to return .mp3 file that I saved in `templates/` in my view.
please help me.
thanks.

Comment: Why would you save an audio file in a templates directory?

Comment: what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Don't** save your mp3 files where your `template` folder exists. save user uploaded content to [MEDIA_ROOT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-MEDIA_ROOT) and save static contents (like css, js and not user content images) in [STATIC_ROOT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#static-files).

**Don't serve static and media files with django codes**. it is bad practice to server static content with django (you have to use something like Nginx for handle static files => see [this](https://gist.github.com/asmallteapot/2038673) and [this](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html) for instance).

if you are insisting to use django for serving static files, In end of your `views.py` related function add these code and return the mp3 file like this:

```
def your_view_function(request):
    # your other codes ...
    file = open("/path/to/your/song.mp3", "rb").read() 
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=filename.mp3' 
    return HttpResponse(file, mimetype="audio/mpeg")
```

Comment: The first paragraph was good. The second is wrong. You should not be invoking Django code to serve static files.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I know this is bad practice. I update my answer is that better now ? thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_music_view(request):
    from django.templatetags.static import static
    music = static('music/Billie Eilish - when the party\'s over (Viga Remix).mp3')
    # static/music/Billie Eilish - when the party\'s over (Viga Remix).mp3
    return redirect(music)
```

Worked for me, and it will not lead ConnectionResetError